# WebRTC - How to identify the source IDs (device IDs) for a MediaStream(Tracks)

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Once I have established a WebRTC connection, I can `getLocalStreams` and `getRemoteStreams`.

The streams have their own ID. Each stream is made of audio/video tracks `MediaStreamTrack`.

I'd like to be able to identify the device/source (ID) used for each track in order to avoid adding a stream that was already added to the connection.

In other word, I was thinking to make a check in `connection.onaddstream` that the stream track is not already present in my list of local or remote streams.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

For each `MediaStreamTrack` you can call `.getCapabilities().deviceId` to get the deviceId.

But I'm not sure if you can use the same device id within the same browser twice.

Comment: hm I get that is it not a function ... (?)

Comment: `getCapabilities()` is a function, `deviceId` is a property. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/getCapabilities

Comment: Unfortunately still not supported by Firefox. getSettings() is the better choice

Comment: Just to note: deviceId gets changed for the same physical device between "origins" or different browsers. So i.e. if you open Chrome and find out deviceId for your camera and then open incognito or another Chrome profile and list devices again, the same device will have a different deviceId.

Answer (score 8):

.getSettings().deviceId on audio/video track (instance of MediaStreamTrack) will return deviceId that is same as deviceId returned from enumerateDevices()

Comment: And the good thing is it's supported by Firefox as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use MediaStreamTrack.id property of MediaStreamTrack.  It Returns a DOM string containing a unique identifier (GUID) for the track; it is generated by the browser.

Comment: Nice to know it but the id you've mentioned is different from the deviceId of camera or mic used for the track.